# multi contextual filters

Tags: views

i have three taxonomy voc for my products. they terms go above 1000 so i am using contextual filters

sub category
brand
price

i want to create contextual filter blocks for these taxonomy
say u click sub category the url has to change to /sb/sub category term
and then u click any brand the url has to be /sb/sub category term/bb/brand term
and then u click price url has to be /sb/sub cate term/bb/brand term/pp/price term

and I should like to have filter block also and hide it once clicked on the voc term.

Very example of this type is in amazon where u filtered down to the product(left side filter blocks)
http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=sa_menu_lapnet9?ie=UTF8&node=2956501011

can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Your question cannot be understood as written, please review it and clarify what you have done and what you want to have happen.  Get rid of the abbreviations and use punctuation.  Phrases like 'sub category brand price' do not make sense as a contextual filter. Also, your URLs are confusing, the intention of the various levels is not clear. Tell us what modules you are using.  For instance, contextual filters belong to views, but you have not mentioned it or how you might have it configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drupal 7, you can use seach_api + facet_api + views ,
Here is a screen cast explaining how to [here](https://vimeo.com/15556855)
and here is an example site : [look at the right side bar](http://drupaljobs.epiqo.com/search/job)

(note that this screen cast is old facet_api can be used without Solr integration)

If you are using Drupal 6 & unsing Shared host solution is [faceted_search](http://drupal.org/project/faceted_search)
If you have a private host the better solution would be : apachesolr + views you can find out a tutorial : [here](http://www.acquia.com/comment/2936)